# Run multiple SSIS projects on the same server in parallel

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent

I have about 7 projects deployed on a SQL Server. Each one contains a MasterPackage which run all the child packages of that project. The issue is that I want all 7 projects to run in parallel, starting at the same time, but as it is right now, they get queued up and start one after another. Can I make all the projects start at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can always schedule packages' executions by the means of SQL Server Agent jobs. You will probably have to create a separate job for each project, but after that, whatever schedule you pick for them should be followed.

Just keep in mind that, if packages push a lot of data through, server might not cope with the total workload, so parallel execution might be slower than a serialised one.